# Python: Finding the input of pandas DatetimeIndex.asof()

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to use `pandas.DatetimeIndex.asof()` to find the closest value to a certain date. However, what is the input for this function exactly?

The [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.asof.html) states that the input is a label but of what format?

To be more specific, I have a DataFrame that looks like this, where the datetime column is set as an index. I want the code to return the index of the row whose datetime is closest to 2018-07-28 13:00:00.

```
datetime             |  price
2018-07-28 12:57:13     8.50
2018-07-28 12:59:45     8.60
2018-07-28 13:01:19     8.70
2018-07-28 13:03:27     8.65
```

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, the use of the word `label` in the documentation is unclear. The format should be the same as your datetime format. For example:

```
# If datetime column is already in datetime format:
df.set_index(df.datetime).asof('2018-07-28 13:00:00')

# If datetime is not already in proper datetime format
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)).asof('2018-07-28 13:00:00')
```

returns a series of the closest datetime found:

```
datetime    2018-07-28 12:59:45
price                       8.6
Name: 2018-07-28 13:00:00, dtype: object
```

## Alternative solution (better IMO)

I think a better way to do this though is just to subtract your target datetime from the `datetime` column, find the minumum, and extract that using `loc`. In this way you can get the true closest value, including from rows that come *after* it (`asof` is limited to the `most recent label up to and including the passed label`, as noted in the docs you linked)

```
>>> df.loc[abs(df.datetime - pd.to_datetime('2018-07-28 13:00:00')).idxmin()]
datetime    2018-07-28 12:59:45
price                       8.6
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Comment: True: the latter option might indeed be better to find the true closest value. Also, do not forget that `DatetimeIndex.asof()` requires a sorted index